# Multiplying Columns using a WITH clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

Hello all Im trying to Find the total value of an order Through Arthmetic(Quanity * Unit_price) which i can do BUT the question wants me to do so using a nest query and a WITH clause. How would I implement the WITH clause?

below is what ive done but not meeting the procedure requirements

```
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDER_ID IN
(SELECT(QUANTITY * UNIT_PRICE) AS TOTAL_VALUE
FROM ORDER_DETAIL)
ODER BY ORDER_ID ASC;
```

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
    ORDER_ID        DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    CUSTOMER_CODE   VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_ID     DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE      DATE        NOT NULL,
    REQUIRED_DATE   DATE,
    SHIPPED_DATE    DATE,
    SHIP_VIA        VARCHAR(40),
    FREIGHT         DECIMAL(10,2)           DEFAULT 0,
    SHIP_NAME       VARCHAR(40),
    SHIP_ADDRESS    VARCHAR(60),
    SHIP_CITY       VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_REGION     VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_POSTAL_CODE    VARCHAR(10),
    SHIP_COUNTRY    VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ORDERS PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_CODE FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_CODE),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLOYEE_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_SHIP_VIA FOREIGN KEY (SHIP_VIA) REFERENCES SHIPPER(COMPANY_NAME)  
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAIL
(
    ORDER_ID         DECIMAL(9) NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_NAME     VARCHAR(40)    NOT NULL,
    UNIT_PRICE       DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    QUANTITY         DECIMAL(9) NOT NULL    DEFAULT 1 ,
    DISCOUNT         DECIMAL(4,2)   NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ORDER_DETAIL PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ORDER_ID FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDERS (ORDER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCT_NAME FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_NAME) REFERENCES PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT CK_ORDER_DETAIL_UNIT_PRICE CHECK (UNIT_PRICE >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_ORDER_DETAIL_QUANTITY CHECK (QUANTITY > 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_ORDER_DETAIL_DISCOUNT CHECK (DISCOUNT between 0 and 1)
);
```

i think i might need to use this table but i am unsure(TABLE PRODUCT)

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
    PRODUCT_NAME    VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    SUPPLIER_NAME   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY_NAME   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY_PER_UNIT   VARCHAR(20),
    UNIT_PRICE      DECIMAL(10,2)   NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    UNITS_IN_STOCK  DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    UNITS_ON_ORDER  DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0, 
    REORDER_LEVEL   DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    DISCONTINUED    CHAR(1)     NOT NULL    DEFAULT 'N',
    CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCT PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CATEGORY_NAME FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_NAME) REFERENCES CATEGORY(CATEGORY_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPLIER_NAME FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_NAME) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(COMPANY_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE CHECK (UNIT_PRICE >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_UNITS_IN_STOCK CHECK (UNITS_IN_STOCK >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_UNITS_ON_ORDER CHECK (UNITS_ON_ORDER >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_REORDER_LEVEL CHECK (REORDER_LEVEL >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_DISCONTINUED CHECK (DISCONTINUED in ('Y','N'))
);
```

This is the exact question

Insert into a file solution1.sql implementation of the following query as
SELECT statement with WITH clause.

Find all orders such that a value of each order is greater than an average value of all orders submitted so far. List in each line of output an order identifier, a total value of an order, and an average value of all orders. The results must be sorted in the descending order of a total value of each order.

"A total value of an order must be computed as the summation of unit price * quantityover all items included in the order. The query must be implemented as a sequence of subquery definitions following WITH keyword and ended with the final SELECT.

(i) The first subquery definition must find a total value of each order together with an order identifier (attribute order_id). "

im currently on (i)

Comment: @Strawberry My APologies i forgot part of the question. Please see my edit it is under the product table

Comment: @Strawberry The second subquery definition must find an average value of all orders.

Comment: @Strawberry also my subquery only selects order_ID not quantity *  unit_price and im unsure why

Comment: @Strawberry I did that before but it has to be nested not just a single select.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes i am aware. The first block of code in this question shows my attempt at the subquery

Comment: @Strawberry Well its not too obvious because i cant see my mistake :P

Comment: @Strawberry is it do with my WHERE IN clause?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for a moment the subsequent requirements, the first block of code might look like this:

```
SELECT o.some
     , o.columns 
     , o.from_orders
     , x.total_value
  FROM orders o
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT order_id
            , SUM(quantity * unit_price) total_value 
         FROM order_detail 
        GROUP 
           BY order_id
     ) x
    ON x.order_id = o.order_id
```

Comment: Yup did that. Still only gets the order_id but

Comment: the lecture notes are horrible, Even my lab professor says dont use them. the subject that does mysql has a high fail rate because no one learns from the classes. Thats why i post so much on this site because people here teach me what uni doesn't :/

Comment: Well, if you select several columns, you end up with several columns. The assertion that this 'still only gets the order_id' is patently false.

Comment: dunno, maybe my mysql is broken

Comment: If it was broken it would return nothing. Maybe edit your question with the latest incarnation of your query